# Two FireBase Errors in Xcode

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, appirater

I have these two error in my code and I am not sure how to fix them. One of the errors is for Appirater and the other one is for FireBaseAuth. I have looked up both of them and have not been able to find a solution. Below I have posted a screenshot of both Errors I am getting along with my pod file. In addition, I have my project and pod files set up to iOS 14 as a minimum deployment.

[image]

[image]

here is my pod file:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'Chall Champ' do

    use_frameworks!

pod ‘Appirater’

pod ‘Firebase/Core’

pod ‘Firebase/Auth’

pod 'Firebase/Database'

pod ‘Firebase/Analytics’

pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

pod ‘Firebase/Storage’

end
```

I have tried looking things up along with messing with the settings for each one and have not been able to fix it.